# How do i check if file is in use/busy before continue the rest of the code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this part:

```
public string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            string result = "";
            string key = request.QueryString.GetKey(0);
            if (key == "cmd")
            {
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "uploadstatus")
                {
                    switch (Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus)
                    {
                        case "uploading file":
                            return "uploading " + Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages;

                        case "status":
                            return Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages.ToString();

                        case "file uploaded successfully":
                            Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus = "";
                            return "upload completed," + Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages + ","
                               + Youtube_Uploader.time;
                        default:
                            return "upload unknown state";
                    }


                }
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "nothing")
                {
                    return "Connection Success";
                }
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "start")
                {
                    StartRecrod();
                    result = "Recording started";
                }

                if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop")
                {
                    dirchanged = false;
                    StartRecrod();
                    result = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
                    string fileforupload = await WatchDirectory();
                    await WaitForUnlockedFile(fileforupload);
                    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt", true))
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(fileforupload);
                    }
                    uploadedFilesList.Add(fileforupload);
                    Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(uploadedFilesList[0]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = "Nothing have been done";
            }

            return result;

        }
```

Then i have the WatchDirectory method:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher;

private void WatchDirectory()
{
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = userVideosDirectory;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
    watcher.Filter = "*.mp4";
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

The OnChanged event:

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    var info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
    fileforupload = info.FullName;
    while(IsFileLocked(fileforupload) == true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Then the IsFileLocked method:

```
public bool IsFileLocked(string filename)
{
    bool Locked = false;
    try
    {
        FileStream fs =
                    File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        fs.Close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Locked = true;
    }
    return Locked;
}
```

Now the order should be that first it will go to the WatchDirectory and then in the while loop will check if the file is locked/busy once the file is not locked/busy any more continue with the rest of the code the StreamWriter the uploadedFilesList.Add and the Youtube_Uploader...

First i'm not sure if it's the right way to use the While loop with the 100.
And second how do i make that it will first finish the file lock checking before continue ? Now what it does is getting to the WatchDirectory then making the StreamWriter... Not the order i want it to be.

Comment: The answer is more complicated than I want to write up on a Saturday morning, sick and tired. I will say that you need to know these things: `WatchDirectory` returns immediately, it doesn't wait for the events. The `OnChanged` event is raised on a separate thread. You should use a `BackgroundWorker` and `ManualResetEvent`s to signal when files have changed or become unlocked. Don't poll for lock status; either use a timer or see if `FileSystemWatcher` can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem with your code is that it doesn't wait in any useful place, and it does wait in the last place you want:

- You call `WatchDirectory()` and then immediately move on to creating your writer. There's nothing in the `WatchDirectory()` method that would delay its return, so of course you move on to the next statement before anything's happened.
- In the `OnChanged()` method, you poll for the file lock status. But this method is an event handler for the `FileSystemWatcher` event, and will be called in a context where you really don't/shouldn't be delaying the thread.

I would change your code to take advantage of the `async` pattern, not only to fix the problems above, but also to provide asynchronous operation, i.e. to prevent this logic from holding up the rest of your program while it's waiting for something interesting to happen in the watched directory.

Here are new versions of your methods that I think would be better:

```
private async Task<string> WatchDirectoryAsync()
{
    using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        watcher.Path = userVideosDirectory;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
        watcher.Filter = "*.mp4";
        watcher.Changed += (sender, e) => tcs.SetResult(e.FullPath);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        return await tcs.Task;
    }
}

// You can get rid of the OnChanged() method altogether

private async Task WaitForUnlockedFileAsync(string fileName)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            using (IDisposable stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
            { /* on success, immediately dispose object */ }

            break;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            // ignore exception
            // NOTE: for best results, consider checking the hresult value of
            // the exception, to ensure that you are only ignoring the access violation
            // exception you're expecting, rather than other exceptions, like
            // FileNotFoundException, etc. which could result in a hung process
        }

        // You might want to consider a longer delay...maybe on the order of
        // a second or two at least.
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop")
{
    dirchanged = false;
    StartRecrod();
    result = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
    string fileforupload = await WatchDirectoryAsync();
    await WaitForUnlockedFileAsync(fileforupload);
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt",true))
    {
        w.WriteLine(fileforupload);
    }
    uploadedFilesList.Add(fileforupload);                   
    Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(uploadedFilesList[0]);
}
```

Naturally, to use `await` in the above, the code will need to be contained in an `async` method. Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the entire context, it's impossible to say how exactly you'd incorporate that into the program as a whole. But there is lots of advice on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on that topic. The basic idea is that, typically, the calling methods would all have to be turned into `async` methods, up to the top of the stack where the call chain starts (which is often some kind of event handler, invoked when the user performs some kind of input).

In some cases, you can just call the `async` method and ignore the returned `Task` object reference (not ideal), or defer handling of the return value (better). You'll have to decide based on your own scenario what works best in your case.

**EDIT:**

If you cannot or will not change the original calling method to be an `async` method, it is possible to perform these operations synchronously. They can be implemented themselves as synchronous methods as follows:

```
private string WatchDirectory()
{
    using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        watcher.Path = userVideosDirectory;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
        watcher.Filter = "*.mp4";
        watcher.Changed += (sender, e) => tcs.SetResult(e.FullPath);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        return tcs.Task.Result;
    }
}

// You can get rid of the OnChanged() method altogether

private void WaitForUnlockedFile(string fileName)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            using (IDisposable stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
            { /* on success, immediately dispose object */ }

            break;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            // ignore exception
            // NOTE: for best results, consider checking the hresult value of
            // the exception, to ensure that you are only ignoring the access violation
            // exception you're expecting, rather than other exceptions, like
            // FileNotFoundException, etc. which could result in a hung process
        }

        // You might want to consider a longer delay...maybe on the order of
        // a second or two at least.
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Or you could simply consume the asynchronously implemented operations synchronously:

```
if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop")
{
    dirchanged = false;
    StartRecrod();
    result = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
    string fileforupload = WatchDirectoryAsync().Result;
    WaitForUnlockedFileAsync(fileforupload).Wait();
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt",true))
    {
        w.WriteLine(fileforupload);
    }
    uploadedFilesList.Add(fileforupload);                   
    Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(uploadedFilesList[0]);
}
```

You might choose the latter if, for example, you intend to convert your other code to `async` eventually but for some reason just can't right now.

Note that I don't *advise* this sort of approach. These operations are inherently asynchronous; i.e. they depend on and wait for some external activity that is itself not happening synchronously. And so in the long run, your program will work *much* better if it itself is not made to stop its progress while waiting for this external operation.

Comment: Peter i'm sorry i didn't add the complete method in my question of the request.QueryString i added it now to the question please if you can look at it now. The whole method that the if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop") is in is type of string it's part of my web server in this part i'm getting commands and then do stuff for example: if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop") ...

Comment: Peter the problem is that the method is type of string so i'm getting two errors on the await lines on this line: string fileforupload = await WatchDirectory(); Error 4 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<string>'.

Comment: Peter and on this line: await WaitForUnlockedFile(fileforupload); Error 5 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<string>'.

Comment: @Danielvanwolf: have you tried following the advice of the compiler error message? I.e. change the method declaration to `public async Task<string> SendResponseAsync(HttpListenerRequest request)` (note that, by convention, one uses the word "Async" in the actual name of an `async` method).

Comment: @Danielvanwolf: As I mentioned in my answer, use of `await` require that the method be an `async` method. Of course, turning this method into an `async` method in turns changes how it's called. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to offer specific advice, hence the generalized advice in my answer.

Comment: @Danielvanwolf: please see the edit to my answer, addressing possible synchronous alternatives that would effectively solve the immediate problem.

Comment: Peter please look at my new question i did few hours ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461827/how-can-i-use-a-method-async-taskstring-and-return-string look at the UPDATE part in my question there i explain my problem now using the async. So maybe i can use async somehow but then i need to do something with my WebServer class(in my new question) .