# How can I use a method async Task<string> and return string, and then how do I pass a delegate for that method to a constructor and use it later?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await

I have this method that returns `string`:

```
public string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
{
    string result = "";
    string key = request.QueryString.GetKey(0);
    if (key == "cmd")
    {
        if (request.QueryString[0] == "uploadstatus")
        {
            switch (Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus)
            {
                case "uploading file":
                    return "uploading " + Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages;

                case "status":
                    return Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages.ToString();

                case "file uploaded successfully":
                    Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus = "";
                    return "upload completed," + Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages + ","
                       + Youtube_Uploader.time;
                default:
                    return "upload unknown state";
            }


        }
        if (request.QueryString[0] == "nothing")
        {
            return "Connection Success";
        }
        if (request.QueryString[0] == "start")
        {
            StartRecrod();
            result = "Recording started";
        }

        if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop")
        {
            dirchanged = false;
            StartRecrod();
            result = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
            string fileforupload = await WatchDirectory();
            await WaitForUnlockedFile(fileforupload);
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt", true))
            {
                w.WriteLine(fileforupload);
            }
            uploadedFilesList.Add(fileforupload);
            Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(uploadedFilesList[0]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = "Nothing have been done";
    }

    return result;

}
```

The problem is that in this method I'm using in two lines `await`:

```
string fileforupload = await WatchDirectory();
await WaitForUnlockedFile(fileforupload);
```

And getting errors on these two lines. Both two errors are the same:

> Error The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.
>   Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing
>   its return type to `'Task<string>'`.

The question if it's possible to make the `SendResponse()` method to return string since I need it and also to use the `await`?

This is the two methods that's why I need to use `await` in the `SendResponse()` method:

```
private async Task<string> WatchDirectory()
{
    using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        watcher.Path = userVideosDirectory;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
        watcher.Filter = "*.mp4";
        watcher.Changed += (sender, e) => tcs.SetResult(e.FullPath);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        return await tcs.Task;
    }
}

// You can get rid of the OnChanged() method altogether

private async Task WaitForUnlockedFile(string fileName)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            using (IDisposable stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
            { /* on success, immediately dispose object */ }

            break;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            // ignore exception
            // NOTE: for best results, consider checking the hresult value of
            // the exception, to ensure that you are only ignoring the access violation
            // exception you're expecting, rather than other exceptions, like
            // FileNotFoundException, etc. which could result in a hung process
        }

        // You might want to consider a longer delay...maybe on the order of
        // a second or two at least.
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed the method `SendResponse()` to be `async Task<string>`
But then in the `WebServer` class constructor I have this and getting error on this line:

```
WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponseAsync, "http://+:8098/");
```

(SendResponseAsync is the SendResponse changed its name)

The error is:

> Error 1   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Automatic_Record.Form1.SendResponseAync(System.Net.HttpListenerRequest)' has the wrong return type

And WebServer class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Automatic_Record
{
    class WebServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

        public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

            // URI prefixes are required, for example 
            // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

            // A responder method is required
            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("method");

            foreach (string s in prefixes)
                _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

            _responderMethod = method;
            _listener.Start();
        }

        public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
            : this(prefixes, method) { }

        public void Run()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
                try
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                            try
                            {
                                string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(ctx.Request.QueryString);
                                //ctx.Request.QueryString

                                byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                            }
                            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                            finally
                            {
                                // always close the stream
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                            }
                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }
                }
                catch { } // suppress any exceptions
            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2

I tried peter solution so i changed the WebServer class code to the one Peter show in this question solution.

Then in form1 constructor i did:

```
var ws = new WebServer(
            () => Task.Run(request => SendResponseAsync(request)),
            "http://+:8098/");
            ws.Run();
```

Then the method SendResponseAsync:

```
public async Task<string> SendResponseAsync(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            string result = "";
            string key = request.QueryString.GetKey(0);
            if (key == "cmd")
            {
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "uploadstatus")
                {
                    switch (Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus)
                    {
                        case "uploading file":
                            return "uploading " + Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages;

                        case "status":
                            return Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages.ToString();

                        case "file uploaded successfully":
                            Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus = "";

                            return "upload completed," + Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages + ","
                               + Youtube_Uploader.time;

                        default:
                            return "upload unknown state";
                    }


                }
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "nothing")
                {

                    return "Connection Success";
                }
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "start")
                {
                    StartRecrod();
                    result = "Recording started";
                }


                if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop")
                {
                    dirchanged = false;
                    StartRecrod();
                    result = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
                    string fileforupload = await WatchDirectory();
                    await WaitForUnlockedFile(fileforupload);
                    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt", true))
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(fileforupload);
                    }
                    uploadedFilesList.Add(fileforupload);
                    Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(uploadedFilesList[0]);
                }


            }
            else
            {
                result = "Nothing have been done";
            }

            return result;

        }
```

The WatchDirectory:

```
private async Task<string> WatchDirectory()
        {
            using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
            {
                TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

                watcher.Path = userVideosDirectory;
                watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
                watcher.Filter = "*.mp4";
                watcher.Changed += (sender, e) => tcs.SetResult(e.FullPath);
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                return await tcs.Task;
            }
        }
```

And last the WaitForUnlockedFile

```
private async Task WaitForUnlockedFile(string fileName)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IDisposable stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                        FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
                    { /* on success, immediately dispose object */ }

                    break;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    // ignore exception
                    // NOTE: for best results, consider checking the hresult value of
                    // the exception, to ensure that you are only ignoring the access violation
                    // exception you're expecting, rather than other exceptions, like
                    // FileNotFoundException, etc. which could result in a hung process
                }

                // You might want to consider a longer delay...maybe on the order of
                // a second or two at least.
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
    }
```

But getting error on the line:

Task.Run
Severity Code   Description Project File    Line Error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string[]' because it is not a delegate type    Automatic_Record

And also error on the line "http://+:8098/" 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line Error Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Func>

Comment: Why exactly you don't want to make SendResponse async?

Comment: Juan i want to make it async but not sure how, since how i will be able to return string ? I'm returning the variable result which is string. If i will make the SendResponse async how will i return the result ?

Comment: @Daniel you don't. You return a task that represents a future string value. Your method is intrinsically asynchronous, stop trying to force it to be otherwise.

Comment: @Danielvanwolf: please note that you've essentially asked two questions here. One (the first, i.e. how to change the method to be able to use `await`) I answered in my answer to your previous question. The other (the second, i.e. how to now use that `async` method with your `WebServer` class), I've answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33461915) [Yuval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870803/yuval-itzchakov) says (and as my answer to your previous question said), once you start with `async`, it generally has to propagate all the way up the call stack. That said, there are alternatives:

- As I mentioned in my previous answer, you can synchronously wait on asynchronous operations. Not ideal, really just a stop-gap measure until you can improve the code further, but it can work.
- You can capture the asynchronous operation (i.e. the `Task`) and use that later.

In your specific example, the second option should work just fine. I.e. the first thing you need to fix is simply to adjust your constructor so that it can accept the asynchronous method. Then you can call that method later, preferably asynchronously.

For example:

```
class WebServer
{
    private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
    private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, Task<string>> _responderMethod;

    public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, Task<string>> method)
    {
        if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

        // URI prefixes are required, for example 
        // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

        // A responder method is required
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("method");

        foreach (string s in prefixes)
            _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

        _responderMethod = method;
        _listener.Start();
    }

    public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, Task<string>> method, params string[] prefixes)
        : this(prefixes, method) { }

    public void Run()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
            try
            {
                while (_listener.IsListening)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async (c) =>
                    {
                        var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                        try
                        {
                            string rstr = await _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                            System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(ctx.Request.QueryString);
                            //ctx.Request.QueryString

                            byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                        }
                        catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                        finally
                        {
                            // always close the stream
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                        }
                    }, _listener.GetContext());
                }
            }
            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
        _listener.Close();
    }
}
```

Of course, with the changed constructor, any *other* callers (if any exist) will also have to be changed. Ideally, you would go change the code related to those callers so that it also follows the `async` model, taking full advantage and gaining the full benefits of that approach.

But again, if you cannot or will not do that, it is possible to adapt older synchronous code to the asynchronous model. E.g. if you have something like this:

```
var server = new WebServer(SomeOtherSendResponse, "http://+:8098/");
```

…you could change it to something like this:

```
var server = new WebServer(
    request => Task.Run(() => SomeOtherSendResponse(request)),
    "http://+:8098/");
```

You could alternatively create a constructor overload to wrap the synchronous method for any such callers, so that the original call site can remain the same:

```
public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
    : this(request => Task.Run(() => method(request)), prefixes)
{ }
```

Note that by following `async` all the way up the call stack, none of the places in the code where the operation would have to wait for an extended period of time on some asynchronous event or action will cause the code to block. Instead, they simply return control to the executing thread, allowing the framework to continue execution of the `async` method later if and when the asynchronous event or action occurs or completes.

Were you to attempt to "solve" the problem by simply waiting synchronously for the asynchronous operation to complete, you would (in this particular case) tie up a thread pool thread, blocking it until it could proceed. This way, the thread pool thread is returned to the pool as soon as the asynchronous operation is started and your program won't require the use of a thread pool thread again for that operation until the operation itself actually completes.

*As an aside: it is not recommended as a general rule to have code that will ignore literally every exception that could occur. You should catch only those exceptions that you expect to occur and which you know for sure are safe to ignore. Even there, you should at least report them somehow to aid in yours or a user's ability to diagnose problems that are not in your code. Other exceptions can easily leave your program's execution in a corrupt state. At best, those kinds of problems will be **extremely** difficult to diagnose and fix and at worst you could wind up corrupting user state, output data, etc.*

Comment: Peter i tried your solution using the var ws = new WebServer(
            () => Task.Run(request => SendResponseAsync(request)),
            "http://+:8098/");
            ws.Run(); but getting error on the Task.Run line Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string[]' because it is not a delegate type Automatic_Record and also error on the line "http://+:8098/" Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Func<System.Net.HttpListenerRequest, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>>

Comment: Peter i also updated my question again to show what i did and what errors i get. I changed the WebServer code according to the one you suggested here then using the method SendResponseAsync with the async Task<string> and using the WatchDirectory and WaitForUnlockedFile but getting errors on the constructor.

Comment: Sorry...typo in my reply (that's the risk you take when you don't include a complete code example, as answer code doesn't get run through a compiler to catch dumb mistakes like that :)). I will update the answer with the correct syntax. But please note that you are also misusing the constructor: the `request => Task.Run(() => ...)` syntax is needed **only if you are using a non-async method**. If you are using `SendResponseAsync()`, then you just need `new WebServer(SendResponseAsync, "http://+:8098/")`. I.e. the method does not need to be wrapped in a lambda, because it's already async.

Comment: @Daniel: also, do make sure you've actually updated the `WebServer` class as I've indicated. The parameter type for `method` must change from `Func<HttpListenerRequest, string>` to `Func<HttpListenerRequest, Task<string>>`

Answer (score 5):

> The question if it's possible to make the SendResponse to return
>   string since i need it and also to use the await ?

Async is "all the way". It means that once you start using `await` in your code, your method signature propagates upwards, going through your entire call-stack. 
This means that any `async` method in your code has to return either a `Task` or a `Task<T>` and have the `async` modifier added to it, in-order for the compiler to detect that this is an async-method and needs to be transformed into a state-machine.

What this means is that this synchronous signature:

```
public string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
```

Needs to turn into an asynchronous signature:

```
public async Task<string> SendResponseAync(HttpListenerRequest request)
```

There *is* an option of synchronously blocking on your code using `Task.Result`. I would not recommend it, as [*you shouldn't block on async code*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). This leads to nothing more than trouble (usually deadlocks).

Comment: Yuval i added to my question my WebServer class code since in the constructor i'm getting error in the constructor when making instance to the WebServer that use the SendResponseAsync method. If you can check it please.

Comment: @Danielvanwolf You can't await inside a constructor.

Comment: So i can't instance make instance of the WebServer. What a  mess.

Comment: @Danielvanwolf: while Yuval's statement that you can't await inside a constructor is correct, a) you don't need to await in a constructor here (you don't actually call the async method there, you just store the delegate referencing the method), and b) while constructors themselves cannot be async, a common alternative is to use an `async` factory method, which does allow to asynchronously initialize whatever the constructor needs, and then to also return the new object asynchronously. `async` is not "a mess", but it does require thinking about certain implementation details in a new way.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `SendResponse` as a `Task<string>`. This says that this Task will return a string.

```
public async Task<string> SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

And in whenever you're calling it:

```
string result = await SendRespone(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your latest compile errors are due to not providing a lambda with the correct signature to the ***WebServer*** class. So you need to either change what you're passing the constructor, or what it expects. With the way you've implemented ***WebServer***, it needs a non-asynchronous method for **_responderMethod**. Thus trying to make *SendResponse()* async is counter productive. I would strongly suggest refactoring either ***WebServer*** to process responses asynchronously, or go back to making *SendResponse()* non-async.

If you'd like to get your code to compile as is you could try something like this:

```cs
var ws = new WebServer(
        request =>
           {
              var t = SendResponseAsync(request);
              t.Wait();
              return t.Result;
           },
        "http://+:8098/");
        ws.Run();
```

You might also have to wrap the lambda in the correct delegate type like so:

```cs
var ws = new WebServer(
        new Func<HttpListenerRequest, string>(request =>
           {
              var t = SendResponseAsync(request);
              t.Wait();
              return t.Result;
           }),
        "http://+:8098/");
        ws.Run();
```

Comment: The proposed change the OP is following (i.e. mine) involves changing the `WebServer` class to operate with asynchronous methods. Assuming the OP followed my instructions, it will compile fine (that he's getting a compiler error suggests he didn't follow my instructions). Your proposal here defeats the whole purpose of making `SendResponse()` into an `async` method. The OP might as well just put the blocking calls in `SendResponse()` itself. Note also that there's no need to call `Wait()` explicitly; getting the `Result` property value will block until a result value is available.

Comment: Yeah definitely, the latest code he posted for WebServer and SendResponse are at odds with each other. I also suggested he refactor WebServer to handle the requests asynchronously. This code would simply fix his compile error.