# How can i make that the method will return first a string and then will continue the rest of the code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a web server and i added this method:

```
public async Task<string> SendResponseAsync(HttpListenerRequest request)//public string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            string result = "";
            string key = request.QueryString.GetKey(0);
            if (key == "cmd")
            {
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "uploadstatus")
                {
                    switch (Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus)
                    {
                        case "uploading file":
                            return "uploading " + Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages;

                        case "status":
                            return Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages.ToString();

                        case "file uploaded successfully":
                            Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus = "";
                            Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages + ","
                               + Youtube_Uploader.time;

                        default:
                            return "upload unknown state";
                    }     
                }
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "nothing")
                {
                    return "Connection Success";
                }
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "start")
                {
                    StartRecrod();
                    result = "Recording started";
                }
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop")
                {
                    dirchanged = false;
                    StartRecrod();
                    result = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
                    string fileforupload = await WatchDirectory();
                    await WaitForUnlockedFile(fileforupload);
                    uploadedFilesList.Add(fileforupload);
                    Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(fileforupload);//uploadedFilesList[0]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = "Nothing have been done";
            }
            return result;
        }
```

The problem is in this part:

```
result = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
string fileforupload = await WatchDirectory();
await WaitForUnlockedFile(fileforupload);
```

The problem is that it will not return yet the result untill it will finish the await.
But i need to make somehow that it will first return the result and after it it will make the rest.

This is the WatchDirectory method:

```
private async Task<string> WatchDirectory()
        {
            using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
            {
                TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

                watcher.Path = userVideosDirectory;
                watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
                watcher.Filter = "*.mp4";
                watcher.Changed += (sender, e) => tcs.SetResult(e.FullPath);
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                return await tcs.Task;
            }
        }
```

And the method WaitForUnlockedFile:

```
private async Task WaitForUnlockedFile(string fileName)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IDisposable stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                        FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
                    { /* on success, immediately dispose object */ }

                    break;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
        }
```

UPDATE:

This is how i'm making instance for the WebServer in the form1 constructor and using the method SendResponseAsync.

```
var ws = new WebServer(
            request => Task.Run(() => SendResponseAsync(request)),
            "http://+:8098/");
```

And this is the WebServer class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Automatic_Record
{
    class WebServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, Task<string>> _responderMethod;

        public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, Task<string>> method)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

            // URI prefixes are required, for example 
            // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

            // A responder method is required
            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("method");

            foreach (string s in prefixes)
                _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

            _responderMethod = method;
            _listener.Start();
        }

        public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, Task<string>> method, params string[] prefixes)
            : this(prefixes, method) { }

        public void Run()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
                try
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async (c) =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                            try
                            {
                                string rstr = await _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(ctx.Request.QueryString);
                                //ctx.Request.QueryString

                                byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                            }
                            catch (Exception error)
                            {

                                string ttt = error.ToString();
                            } // suppress any exceptions
                            finally
                            {
                                // always close the stream
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                            }
                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }
                }
                catch { } // suppress any exceptions
            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You try something like 'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);' ?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here - what do `WatchDirectory` and `WaitForUnlockedFile` do? How do you expect to use the result of a method before it's completed? You need to explain this more thoroughly.

Comment: Ant i will explain. This method is part of my web server on c#, I'm using this method to get commands from my java program the client. The client side send commands every second and i'm checking it in the method and return to the client a string according to the case. In this case "stop" like in other cases like "start" i return a string to the client the java side and in the java side i'm using texttospeech to say the string. In this case it should say: Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube the problem is that the AWAIT lines make it hold and only after the await.

Comment: And only after the await is finished it's sending the string "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube". The problem is that this await take some time. It might take a second and sometimes 30 seconds or more. What the await do ? In the WatchDirectory and WaitForUblockedFile i'm waiting for a file to be written. Sometimes the file might be 1kb and some times 1GB. So what i need is to find a way to first return this string to the client and then make this await by logic. And they both should be inside the "stop" IF.

Comment: Ant i also updated my question with the both missing methods.

Comment: If you want to wait until you get result, then it means that you want not asynchronous code, but synchronous code. So you should just remove async/await keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have multiple "checkpoints" during the operation of the `SendResponseAsync()` method, and at each you want to be able to send a response to the client with some status message (e.g. you want to report the result `"Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube"` after the call to `WatchDirectory()` completes, but before you execute the call to `WaitForUnlockedFile()`).

The basic problem is that the `SendResponseAsync()` method can, just as would be the case with any other method `async` or otherwise, only return a single value. You can't have any method return more than once<sup>†</sup>, and that's just as true for `async` methods as any other type.

So, what to do? Well, it's impossible to say for sure without seeing the code in context (i.e. without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem). But one idiomatic approach in C# would be to use the `IProgress<T>` interface, to allow the caller of your method to be called back with status values, so that it can handle them appropriately (e.g. by sending them to the client).

For example, you could change your method to look like this:

```
public async Task SendResponseAsync(
        HttpListenerRequest request, IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        string key = request.QueryString.GetKey(0);
        if (key == "cmd")
        {
            if (request.QueryString[0] == "uploadstatus")
            {
                switch (Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus)
                {
                    case "uploading file":
                        progress.Report("uploading " + Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages);
                        return;

                    case "status":
                        progress.Report(Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages.ToString());
                        return;

                    case "file uploaded successfully":
                        Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus = "";
                        Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages + ","
                           + Youtube_Uploader.time;

                    default:
                        progress.Report("upload unknown state");
                        return;
                }     
            }
            if (request.QueryString[0] == "nothing")
            {
                progress.Report("Connection Success");
                return;
            }
            if (request.QueryString[0] == "start")
            {
                StartRecrod();
                progress.Report("Recording started");
            }
            if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop")
            {
                dirchanged = false;
                StartRecrod();
                string fileforupload = await WatchDirectory();
                progress.Report("Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube");
                await WaitForUnlockedFile(fileforupload);
                uploadedFilesList.Add(fileforupload);
                Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(fileforupload);//uploadedFilesList[0]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            progress.Report("Nothing have been done");
        }
    }
```

Assuming the code used to look something like this:

```
string result = await SendResponseAsync(request);

SendResultToClient(result);
```

Then you might call the new vesion of the method something like this:

```
await SendResponseAsync(request, new Progress<string>(s => SendResultToClient(s)));
```

That would create a new instance of `Progress<T>` (a built-in class that implements `IProgress<T>`) that will call your `SendResultToClient()` method to send the status message to the client.

A variation on the above would be to allow the method to still return one result, and use the `progress` parameter only for those results that need to be returned before the method has completed. In that case, all of the places where I changed `return ...some string value...;` to `progress.Report(...some string value...);` would go back to being the way they were in your original code, you would still declare the method as `async Task<string>`, return the `result` value, and of course use that value to send the result to the client on completion of the awaited call to `SendResponseAsync()`. I.e. the call site wouldn't change, except for adding the `IProgress<T>` argument.

**EDIT:**

To address the added information in the question:

1. First of all, you are calling the `WebServer` constructor incorrectly. The `WebServer` code you are using looks exactly like [the code I helped someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33467125) with a couple of weeks ago. In that question, the goal was to be able to pass an `async` method to the constructor. The example of using `Task.Run()` was *only* for the scenario where there is some *other* caller using `WebServer` that did not have an `async` method to pass. Wrapping the call to the `async` method in a task is completely wrong and will not produce the desired results. (Actually, the code you posted should not even compile, as `Task.Run()` is returning `Task<Task<string>>` while the delegate is supposed to return only `Task<string>`. Assuming it does compile, presumably there some *other* hack not shown that works around that compile-time error.)
2. To actually use the advice above, you need to refactor the rest of the code so that it can work with the suggested design. In particular, the `async` method needs to be passed the appropriate `IProgress<T>` instance which is used for reporting status. The only way to do that is to change the signature of the delegate that is eventually used to call that method, and then later of course to pass the `IProgress<T>` instance needed. I will provide an example of what that change might look like below…

First, your `WebServer` class needs to change, to accept the different method signature:

```
class WebServer
{
    private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
    private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, IProgress<string>, Task> _responderMethod;

    public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, IProgress<string>, Task> method)
    {
        if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

        // URI prefixes are required, for example 
        // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

        // A responder method is required
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("method");

        foreach (string s in prefixes)
            _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

        _responderMethod = method;
        _listener.Start();
    }

    public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, IProgress<string>, Task> method, params string[] prefixes)
        : this(prefixes, method) { }

    public void Run()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
            try
            {
                while (_listener.IsListening)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async (c) =>
                    {
                        var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                        try
                        {
                            await _responderMethod(ctx.Request, new Progress<string>(rstr =>
                            {
                                byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                            });
                            System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(ctx.Request.QueryString);
                            //ctx.Request.QueryString

                            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                        }
                        catch (Exception error)
                        {

                            string ttt = error.ToString();
                        } // suppress any exceptions
                        finally
                        {
                            // always close the stream
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                        }
                    }, _listener.GetContext());
                }
            }
            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
        _listener.Close();
    }
}
```

Then the constructor call should simply look like this:

```
var ws = new WebServer(SendResponseAsync, "http://+:8098/");
```

Where, of course, you have modified `SendResponseAsync()` as I've explained above so that it can receive an instance of `IProgress<T>` as a parameter.

Having done all that, then the block of code in your `WebServer` class's `Run()` method that writes result text to the response's output stream is encapsulated in an anonymous method used as the `Action<string>` delegate for the `Progress<string>` instance passed to the `_responseMethod` delegate invocation.

**NOTE:**

The above may or may not be correct in your scenario. Again, without a good code example it's impossible to know for sure. But it is important to keep in mind that the `Progress<T>` class uses the current `SynchronizationContext` at the time it's created in order to raise its `ProgressChanged` event. In many cases, this is exactly what you want. But depending on the context of the call here, it's possible you will wind up using the thread pool to raise the event, which introduces the possibility of out-of-order callbacks. This would of course cause the data to appear in the response stream in the wrong order.

So as an alternative to using `Progress<T>`, you may want to use a custom class that raises the event synchronously. For example:

```
class SynchronousProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    public event EventHandler<T> ProgressChanged;

    public SynchronousProgress() { }

    public SynchronousProgress(Action<T> callback)
    {
        ProgressChanged = (sender, e) => callback(e);
    }

    public void Report(T t)
    {
        EventHandler<T> handler = ProgressChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, t);
        }
    }
}
```

To use that, just replace `Progress` with `SynchronousProgress` in the `Run()` method example above.

† - Ignoring iterator methods of course. Those have different semantics, allowing `yield return` to be executed more than once. But they also do not work well with `async`, so aren't relevant here.

Comment: Peter thank you. You got the idea and the problem. Now i added to my question UPDATE and there i added the way i'm making instance for my WebServer in form1 constructor and why i can't make it like you did: await SendResponseAsync(request, new Progress<string>(s => SendResultToClient(s))); i also added the WebServer class. Maybe you can look at it and see how to make the instance.

Comment: @Sharon: Your code looks just like I [code I helped with](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33467125) 2 weeks ago. But your code example is misusing it. Theres no need to use `Task.Run()` when calling the `WebServer` class constructor if the callback being passed is in fact already `async`, as is the case in your code example. I will edit my answer to try to address the new question you've added, but please note that I did answer the original question and that you should try to not expand questions once asked. If you get a good answer, just accept that and post a new question with the new details.